# Rails convention for non-index integer fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, conventions

I want to keep statistics of records (let's say books), that how many times they've displayed on a page. I've added an integer column called featured, based on that attribute, I'm fetching records which has less count of `featured`. This will reduce inequality and I will be happy, because I am a communist :)

```
def foo
  @books = Book.order(:featured).take(5)
  @books.each { |book| book.update_columns(featured: book.featured+1) }
  render 'bar'  
end
```

Suddenly I've realized that attributes with `ed` suffix ( past (perfect) tense ) are generally used for boolean fields (e.g. `book.published?`, `book.featured?`, `book.approved?`), which is more intuitive. And if I keep `featured` as an integer attribute name, this may confuse other newcomers in future.

So, is there a more readable convention for integer fields?

Comment: No, there is no naming convention. But I would call the column `views`  or `page_views` not `viewed`. `featured` does not really work here since it does not have the same meaning when used as a noun.

Comment: If you want a convention then its that if you need a comment to explain what the column does the naming probably sucks.

Comment: @max when discussing with teammates, i just made a sentence like this: "this entry has been featured x times". that's why i chose this. then, as described above, i've realized it's not a good fit. 
so, you say `views` is more readable, yeah?

Comment: Views is noun that is countable so in that sense its a good choice. "this entry has been featured x times" is very different from "this entry has x features". If you had to use it would call the column `times_featured` or something that clearly explains what it is.

Comment: `times_featured` fits better. thanks @max -))

Answer (score 0):

i guess not, even you create a "boolean check" with featured as u show us u'll use "featured?"

Comment: of course. 
for sake of readability, we use `@book.published?` (=>t/f). tihs gives the sense like you are asking question. `(is/has) this book published?`